# Injecting XML schema defaults into documents with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd, default-value

Here we have a simple XML schema:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="is-foo" type="xs:boolean" default="true" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="is-bar" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="optional" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Just recursive `<item>` nodes with optional `is-foo`/`is-bar` boolean attributes, defaulting to `true` and `false` respectively.

Now, how are these default values useful, in the context of reading XML data in PHP? If I have a valid XML document:

```
<item is-foo="false" is-bar="false">
    <item is-bar="true">
        <item>
            <item is-foo="true">
                <item />
                <item is-foo="true" />
            </item>
        </item>
        <item is-foo="true" is-bar="true" />
    </item>
</item>
```

Against which I run:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('./test.xml');
var_dump($document->schemaValidate('./test.xsd'));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
foreach ($xpath->query('//item') as $item) {
    echo $item->getNodePath() . PHP_EOL
        . '  is-foo : ' . $item->getAttribute('is-foo') . PHP_EOL
        . '  is-bar : ' . $item->getAttribute('is-bar') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I get the following output (*which, while expected, is unfortunate*):

```
bool(true)
/item
  is-foo : false
  is-bar : false
/item/item
  is-foo :
  is-bar : true
/item/item/item[1]
  is-foo :
  is-bar :
/item/item/item[1]/item
  is-foo : true
  is-bar :
/item/item/item[1]/item/item[1]
  is-foo :
  is-bar :
/item/item/item[1]/item/item[2]
  is-foo : true
  is-bar :
/item/item/item[2]
  is-foo : true
  is-bar : true
```

The issue here being all of the empty attribute values.

Aside from programatically injecting default values into the documents (*which would require interpreting the schema for any reusability*) are there any options to transform an XML document to include default values as defined in the corresponding schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the DOM extension.

libxml doesn't do this unless the [`XML_SCHEMA_VAL_VC_I_CREATE`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaValidOption) is set on the schema validation context in use, and currently [it isn't](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/dom/document.c#2025).

I've created a [patch](https://github.com/DaveRandom/php-src/commit/d7b05a192953e4fc4efb1b05c6337d80fa159ee4) that should hopefully expose this functionality by means of an additional `$flags` argument to `schemaValidate()`/`schemaValidateSource()` and an new `LIBXML_SCHEMA_CREATE` constant ([example target code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zWG0ZE)), but I've yet to test it as I don't have a usable build environment readily available.

*EDIT*

The patch has now been tested and I've created a [PR](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/325) to merge into the 5.5 branch.

*EDIT 2*

The PR has now been merged into master and the feature should be available from PHP 5.5.2.

*EDIT 3*

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/qCdY3)

Comment: Cool beans on the patch :)

Comment: @Bracketworks For completeness: This is now available in general release on the 5.5 branch, since 5.5.2.